# How i can make script(simple .py file) for fetch data from magento using python?

Tags: python-2.7, magento-1.3

In this only create python file in one method is read, in this method through fetch the data of magento.

How i can do this, anyone can help me ?

Comment: please add information on magento version used and what kind of data are you planning to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from magento.api import API
import warnings
with  API('url','username','passward') as magento:

```
result=magento.call('catalog_product.info',[int(1),None,None,'id'])
print result
```